# Incompatible gettext and git installed by Homebrew?

Tags: git, installation, homebrew, gettext, system-administration

```
$ git status
On branch master
...

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gettext
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/envsubst
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/envsubst
  Reason: image not found
/usr/local/bin/gettext.sh: line 87: 10800 Abort trap: 6           envsubst "$1"
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gettext
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/envsubst
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/envsubst
  Reason: image not found
/usr/local/bin/gettext.sh: line 87: 10841 Abort trap: 6           envsubst "$1"
nothing to commit, working tree clean

 $ ls /usr/local/Cellar/gettext
 0.19.8.1
```

It seems my Git installed by Homebrew wants to access /usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.19.4 which does not exist?

I have tried

```
git reinstall git
```

in vain.

Assuming I just need to install gettext of the version 0.19.4, I've tried to find methods to install a Homebrew "formula" of a specific version, but all solutions found on the web have proved to be outdated and not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homebrew's gettext is not linked to /usr/local/bin by default. An older version may have been linked at some point and that binary points to the outdated installation. Why git is linked to that is another question (assuming you're using Homebrew's git).

First try `brew unlink gettext` and `brew reinstall git --force-bottle`. If that doesn't work you can overwrite the old linked version with `brew link --overwrite gettext`.

Comment: It has to be `brew link --overwrite --force gettext`.